# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

### OMG, I can't believe that Joomla Stack Exchange has never rolled out this feature before!

Let's fix this oversight, right now and forever.

---

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown until the end of the calendar year.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is first and foremost intended to be a community building feature.  The goal is for Joomla users to find out about the events, products and services that will be *relevant and valuable* to them.  Hopefully this will spur new engagement within JSE and motivate Joomla users to do more and be more outside of JSE.

Since this is the inaugural year for this offering, the rules will be very welcoming about what can be advertised.  For example, you might promote the following things:

- JoomlaDay
- JoomlaCamp
- Pizza, Bugs & Fun
- User Group Meetings
- Akeeba Backup for Joomla
- TinyMCE for Joomla
- Plotalot
- RSForms
- SiteGround Joomla Hosting
- RocketTheme Templates for Joomla
- Marketing Rocket for Joomla
- A List of Joomla Certified Administrators
- Joomla Social Networks
- the potential list goes on and on.

There is a caveat to this generosity though.  If you are offering a product or service that generates revenue, we fully expect that you will increase your volunteerism in this community.  This is a matter of decency, respect and balance.  If you work for VirtueMart and post an ad for VirtueMart, it will be expected that you show your appreciation by having your employees help to field questions which are tagged with [virtuemart](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtuemart).  By effect, everyone wins -- this is what we are striving for.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against re-posting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to re-post it. It may be helpful to give it a new face (create a fresh new image) in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
    [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

    [1]: http://image-url
    [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag (and is only available to diamond moderators). In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 250 x 300 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/9459).

Want to see how other Stack Exchange sites' Community Ads look? [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/2943403) [CodeReviewMeta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9459/141885) [WordPress](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4673)

---

**Update**:

Currently JSE is not able to utilise this feature because JSE is still in Beta status.  I have asked for this feature to be extended to all Stack Exchange sites.
In the meantime, please express your interest in this feature by:

- posting real, legitimate ads
- upvoting the question and
- upvoting any answers that contains an appropriate/Joomla-relevant ad.

This of this as a rehearsal before the stage becomes available.

Comment: I had no idea about this feature.

Comment: Can you confirm @mickmackusa  the preference is for a portrait ad 300h x 250w? (600h x 500w for retina)

Comment: I am continuing to campaign for a barrage of things to help JSE.  Here's one that you can see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351032/352329  I'll add this to my list of inquiries. @PatrickJackson

Answer (score 8):

[image: Joomla Australia Virtual User Group - 3rd Tuesday 0800 UTC]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Bugs & Fun @ Home - Joomla Bug Fixing Program every Saturday]

Answer (score 6):

[image: This was our last meeting. I'll post the new upcoming meeting as soon as we have defined it.]

Comment: your ad looks to be specific for 10/7/20 or is that when the podcast was released?

Dimensions also work better as 300h x 250w for where the ad appears. And it looks like you've linked the image without a URL to click through to :(

Comment: Yes, it was for a specific date. The podcast is produced by Andrea and Carlos. If you need a generic ad, I can ask them for one.

Comment: That would be good - the ads typically are going to run for the remainder of the year once the feature is turned on.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Join us for our monthly Joomla! user group meetup]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Joomla! Pizza, Bugs and Fun - October 17th 2020]

Answer (score 2):

[image: 2020 Joomla Australia Site Awards]