# Announcement: JSE is graduating out of Beta status!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

### WE DID IT! Joomla Stack Exchange is graduating out of beta status.

Joomla Stack Exchange has proven itself to be a valuable and lasting community since 2014 and will become a full "matured" Stack Exchange community.

You can read more about this fantastic achievement here:

1. https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/?cb=1&_ga=2.159865277.1452835825.1639348693-1355521049.1620609038
2. Meta Stack Exchange: [Congratulations to the 58 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/352329)

TL;DR

1. We are going to have another moderator election in 2022.

   I'll be running for moderator again and I hope several other people will join in.  The more candidates, the better the election.
2. We are going to be able to enjoy Community Ads (finally).

   You can see our failed attempt to run Community Ads @ [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/386/12352).  It will give you a pretty good picture of how it will look for JSE.

   I am also entertaining the idea of raising the bar of contribution before being able to submit an ad.  You can see this discussion at: [How to best leverage the Community Ads feature for maximum contribution?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374092/352329)
3. We can start thinking about how JSE can have unique branding.

   I am not graphically inclined, but I would like us to enjoy something more representative of Joomla than our current pale blue J image.  See [what some other sites have done](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Answer (score 5):

This is fantastic news and you Mick and the other Mods are to thank for this achievement.

Answer (score 2):

Well done Mick amazing job by you and all the others who help on JSE.  Really appreciate all you've done this will be a fantastic tool for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Awesome news. Congratulations to Joomla community.

Comment: It is heartening to see that there are at least a few people who know that JSE Meta exists.